# Canceling an auto-renewable subscription

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

From what I've read so far, this isn't possible. The user has to go into their iTunes settings and cancel their membership themselves. However, my app offers a 3-tier subscription. Monthly, yearly and lifetime.

If the user wants to switch to lifetime and they are currently on monthly/yearly, if I don't cancel their monthly/yearly, they'll still keep paying despite having purchased a lifetime membership.

What is a way of handling this?